# Logstash Addtional fields added by Elasticsearch Output or not?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am using logstash. input is jdbc and output is es.

Just wanted to know the fields which I see when using just stout in output are the same fields which will be index to es or es output plug in might add some other extra fields? I have to debug some issue .

When input =jdbc hive, output =csv. Code works.

When input =jdbc hive, output =es. Code fails.

When input =jdbc oracle, output =es. Code works.

When input =csv , output =es. Code works.

So it's crazy. Not able to fix this for two days now.

[Config file logstash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67aJD.jpg)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5To2.jpg)

[Error contd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBi6a.jpg)

Comment: without examples, no one will be able to help you here.

Comment: Examples like ? I attached config file and error. I am just doing a select count(*) from a table;